# Got stuck with O(n*logn)

Tags: python, math, big-o, quicksort

I have a quick sortion:

```
def quickSort(array):
    if len(array) <= 1:
        return array
    else:
        center = array[0]
        l_arr = [n for n in array[1:] if n <= center]
        r_arr = [n for n in array[1:] if n > center]
        return quickSort(left) + [center] + quickSort(right)
```

return value is sorted array now. But what is not clear is that that the algorithm has time complexity n*logn. We will map everything below, e.g. n = 8:

```
 [1, 5, 7, 9, 10, 11, 1, 5] is given, we take the num at 0 which is 1, 
 from then now we compare all items in list as per the code, found 1 <= 1. 
 We put it in the left array. We put the rest in the right array. 
 [1] + [1] + [7, 9, 10, 11, 5]. We sort r_arr recursively which give us
 [5] +[5] + [7] + [9, 10, 11]. We sort r_arr again. [] + [9] + [10, 11]. And 
 again. [10] + [11].
 [1, 5, 7, 9, 10, 11, 1, 5] n elements
 [1] [5, 7, 9, 10, 11, 1, 5]n - 1
 [1][1][5, 7, 9, 10, 11, 5] n - 2
 [1][1][5][7, 9, 10, 11, 5] n - 3
 [1][1][5][5][7, 9, 10, 11] n - 4
 [1][1][5][5][7][9, 10, 11] n - 5 
 [1][1][5][5][7][9][10, 11] n - 6
 [1][1][5][5][7][9][10][1]  n - 7
```

Here I see that we divide  our array 3 times having sub array length of which is factor of 2. So why we have 8 * 3 = 24 operations instead of 8(2+2+2+2) + 3 = 11 operations?

Comment: Who says that there are 24 operations?

Comment: Formula says it. 8 * 3. But why 3 times per total n.

Comment: Which formula? Who says that the formula is correct?

Comment: I just use a simple case to put end values into the formula to understand it.

Comment: Is Big O's n logn

Comment: O(n log n) does not mean that for n=8 there will be *exactly* 8 * log(8) operations (note that the base of the logarithm isn't even specified, because it doesn't matter). It means that if you scale n, then the number of steps of the algorithm will scale proportionally to n times log n (roughly speaking).

Comment: I just dont get why should multiply n times logn

Comment: @yose93 in the above analysis you are only counting the number of times you are calling the function, but you are not counting how many comparisons you need to do each time you call that function.

Comment: You should think of 'Big-O' notation as more of a *qualitative* expression instead of a quantitative one. It's not really meant for crunching numbers so to say - It's meant to simply encapsulate degrees of cost.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have misunderstood what the Big O value of an algorithm actually counts and how it should be interpreted. There are 3 issues to address here:

1. The Big O order of an algorithm doesn't give you an exact number of steps taken, it's a *grouping* of algorithms into classes of behaviour as the number of inputs grows.
2. In the case of Quicksort, it's not the recursive calls that matter, it's the comparisons.
3. Your input is not an average case, it is actually taking *more* than the average number of steps.

First, when people say that Quicksort is an O(N logN) algorithm, what they mean is that the algorithm will take a certain amount of time relative to the number of inputs **as you scale the number of inputs up**. This is called the *asymptotic behaviour* of the algorithm. If you were to generate random input sequences that are longer and longer, and you measured the time taken to sort each of these, you'll notice that those times will grow following a N log(N) *trend*, a line that only subtly deviates from a straight line (but you could make it straight if you used a logarithmic scale on the time axis of your graph).

What it *doesn't* mean is that for any given input, the algorithm will take *exactly* N times log(N) steps. The Big O notation lets you classify algorithms, they give you the *order* of an algorithm, which can be seen as an upper bound for the average case of the algorithm, which then allows you to compare that algorithm with other algorithms that would let you achieve the same goal (sorted output, here) and know something about which one will behave *better* as you give it large inputs. What you care about, when it comes to algorithms, is knowing whether or not the job you have to do will complete in a reasonable amount of time, and the Big O order tells you what algorithms can achieve that.

That's why,  when it comes to asymptotic maths, we remove any constants or lower-order components, because it doesn't matter if you have an algorithm that takes almost 2 times infinite time when given a near infinite number of inputs or only half times near-infinite time. Both would produce straight graphs that reach the *no longer worth waiting for* state at the same *magnitude* of inputs. By the time you are talking about processing billions of inputs per 24 hours, it no longer matters if that's 5 billion or 6 billion inputs, what matters is that if you were to replace the algorithm with one that is O(N^2) then the same job will take *several hundred thousand years*, but if you could find an O(N) algorithm you could cut the time down to the 45 minutes ballpark.

Algorithms typically also have best and worst case scenarios; *some* sorting algorithms hit their best case scenario when the input is already sorted and so only need linear time to produce the same already sorted output in N steps. Conversely, if the input was, say, in *reverse* sorted order, then an algorithm may have to make as many as N times N comparisons, so N squared, which would be a worst-case scenario. That doesn't mean it'll behave like either the best or worst case scenarios for *all* inputs however.

For Quicksort, the best-case scenario still takes O(N logN), by the way, because at best you end up with the pivot value being exactly in the middle for every partitioning step. The worst case for Quicksort is where it always picks the lowest or highest value in the array as the pivot, because then you still haven't actually sorted anything, and your recursive implementation would have to make N recursive calls for each subsequent full partition containing one fewer element each step.

As I stated, we use Big O notation to *classify* algorithms and compare them. It is often better to use a O(N logN) algorithm than it is to use a O(N^2) algorithm, because as the input scales, the O(N logN) algorithm will be (much) faster at completing the task. I say *often* better, because if your inputs are always small, then different factors play, and the 'slow' O(N^2) approach may actually beat the O(N logN) approach because it has much lower *constant* costs, the amount of work required to do a single step.

So your specific input *could* be an a-typical case. It doesn't *have* to follow the ideal N times log(N) number of steps, it could take more if it is tending towards the worst case.

For Quicksort, it is the *comparisons* that count, because that's something that you do more of as N grows. *Just to partition the input around a pivot* takes N-1 steps, because you need first pick your pivot, then compare all N-1 elements to the chosen pivot value. Combining the results (concatenating the recursive call for the first partition plus pivot plus second partition) also has a cost, as you are creating a new list with N elements from inputs. That too takes N steps, but because that's essentially the same number of steps as partitioning, we can disregard that here as a constant cost per N inputs. Similarly, your quicksort implementation does all the pivot comparisons twice, once for each partition.

Note that we are **not counting the recursive calls here**. You used a recursive implementation, but you could also implement Quicksort with a stack and iteration (effectively replacing the call stack Python manages for you with your own stack), and still make the same number of comparisons. So instead of counting recursive calls, each call to `quickSort()` should really be seen as executing *`len(array)`* steps to create the partitions.

For your input, lets count the comparisons needed to create partitions:

- `[1, 5, 7, 9, 10, 11, 1, 5]`, pivot at 1. Compare the 7 other values to it to create the `[1]` and `[5, 7, 9, 10, 11, 5]` partitions: **8 comparisons**.

  - `[1]` is already sorted, return `[1]`.
  - `[5, 7, 9, 10, 11, 5]`, pivot at 5. Compare the other 5 values to 5 to create the `[5]` and `[7, 9, 10, 11]` partitions: **6 comparisons**.

    - `[5]` is already sorted, return `[5]`.
    - `[7, 9, 10, 11]`, pivot at 7. Compare the other 3 values to 7 to create the `[]` and `[9, 10, 11]` partitions: **4 comparisons**.

      - `[]` is already sorted, return `[]`.
      - `[9, 10, 11]`, pivot at 9. Compare the other 2 values to 9 to create the `[]` and `[10, 11]` partitions: **3 comparisons**.

        - `[]` is already sorted, return `[]`.
        - `[10, 11]`, pivot at 10. Compare the 1 single other value to 10 to create the `[]` and `[11]` partitions: **2 comparisons**.

          - `[]` is already sorted, return `[]`.
          - `[11]` is already sorted, return `[11]`.

That makes 8 + 6 + 4 + 3 + 2 == **23 steps**. That's already a lot closer to the 'predicted' 24 steps, but take into account I didn't count testing the `[]` and `[1]`, `[5]`, `[7]` and `[11]` partitions, which all result in a simple `return array`. In actual fact, your sample case approaching the worst-case scenario, which would take 8 + 7 + 6 + 5 + 4 + 3 + 2 = 35 steps. While that's higher than the 'ideal' 24 steps Big O would posit,  you'll also note that this is lower than the strict N^2 == 8 * 8 == 64 number, but again, we are talking about *asymptotic behaviour*, not exact counts.

Again, that's because Big O tells us Quicksort'll take between O(N logN) and O(N^2) steps, not *exactly* those number of steps. In reality, Quicksort's worst-case scenario takes (N * (N + 1)) // 2 steps (that's because in that case you hit the the arithmetic series, `N + N - 1 + N - 2 + ... + 1`, a [triangle number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number)). But remove the constants and via `O((N * N) // 2) == 1/2 * N^2` you are left with O(N^2).

The ideal case, on the other hand, will divide each array input exactly down the middle and process (N - 1) // 2 elements in each of the two recursive calls. So in the end to go *at most* log(N) levels deep (after log^2(N) steps dividing the arrays perfectly into halves you end up with N arrays with 0 or 1 elements), and each level of recursion makes *at most* N comparisons across all the calls, and so you make, *at most* O(N logN) comparisons in total. Note the *at most* in there, because you don't bring along the pivot to the next level so the actual numbers are a little lower but can be ignored as they are just more constants. Reshuffling your sample array to construct an *ideal* input gives me `[7, 5, 1, 1, 5, 10, 9, 11]` which results in 8 + 4 + 3 + 2 == 17 actual comparisons.

But *as you scale up N* you'll notice that the number of steps in relationship to the input size grows faster than linear; as the input size grows from A - 1 to A you can see the algorithm needs more than 1 additional unit of time to complete the task. Instead, it takes A // 2 more time, *roughly*. The ideal 9-element input takes 9 + 4 + 4 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 2 = 25 steps, the ideal 10-element input takes 10 + 5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 2 + 2 = 28 steps, 11 elements would take 11 + 5 + 5 + 3 + 3 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 2 = 35 steps, 12 elements == 12 + 6 + 5 + 3 + 3 + 3 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 2 == 40 steps. Those numbers follow the same line as N * log^2(N), which (rounded down) would be 28, 33, 38 and 43; Quicksort grows by the exact same delta, it's only 3 'units' off! Similarly, for the worst-case scenario, Quicksort adds an additional A steps when you go from A - 1 to A, just like an 'ideal' O(N^2) algorithm would take (2A - 1) units of extra time for the same increment.

You may want to study [Kahn Academy's analysis of Quicksort's running time](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/algorithms/quick-sort/a/analysis-of-quicksort), which explains more about the best, average and worst-case scenarios of Quicksort as part of an excellent intro to algorithms. You may want to start with their [section on asymptotic notation](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/algorithms#asymptotic-notation) for another run through what I just laid out above.